# Cant acess laravel object property

Tags: php, laravel

I have a question, i cant seem to get the property of a return from my controller in laravel.

```
    $machineLogs = MachineLog::whereHas( 'groups', function( $group ) use (&$componentId) {
        $group->whereHas( "units", function( $unit ) use (&$componentId) {
            $unit->whereHas( "components", function( $component ) use (&$componentId) {
                $component->where( "Component", $componentId );
            } );
        } );
    } )->take( $limit )->get();


    foreach ($machineLogs as $log)
    {
        echo $log->oId;
    }
```

I cant seem to access any properties of the object that is given back i can however get back the array that is associated, what am i doing wrong?

```
[
{
"oId": 411197,
"active": false,
}
]
```

The object itself has different properties that i am trying to reach like so $log->oId to get the oId back from the log.

I can access the groups that are related to the MachineLog model.
Result for { dump($log); }

```
App\MachineLog {#388 ▼
  #primaryKey: "Oid"
  #table: "Log"
  #connection: "testdb"
  #appends: array:1 [▼
    0 => "groups"
  ]
  #fillable: array:2 [▼
    0 => "name"
    1 => "oId"
  ]
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:20 [▼
    "Oid" => 10401419
    "Active" => true
    "Speed" => "0"
    "Weight" => "0"
    "Act" => "0"
    "Code" => ""
    "Control" => false
    "Type" => 1
    "Max" => 1
    "Name" => "Arl"
    "Number" => "9-10"
    "Mode" => 1
    "Recipe" => ""
    "Line" => "-1"
```

Comment: Can you show us which operation is failing and how?

Comment: Well i dont get anything back if i try to access a property of the object. I can however just echo the object itself with echo $log

Comment: Again: Can you tell me how you try to access a property of the object?

Comment: $log->oId; i try to access the property like this

Comment: Where did you try to refer that? Outside the foreach, right?

Comment: inside the foreach im trying to echo the oId of the logs

Comment: Okay, I give up. Provide much more details and then ping me.

Comment: what does this output? 
  foreach ($machineLogs as $log)
    {
      dump($log);
    }